# MVC4 Entity Framework one paticular column not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an infuriating issue where one paticular column in my entity will not save/update.  I have tried numerous methods of updating the row such as manally assigning each property I want to update, to where I am now (see code block below).  2 columns update and save as expected (absent_type_id, and point_value) however no matter what I do the "description" column just will not save.

I have checked the debugger to see what the value is before the db.SaveChanges(); and confirmed it is set to the new value; however, selecting the row after the save (and checking the database) shows that the others values are updated, but the description reverts back to what it was...why could this be?

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateOccurrence(int occ_id,
                                       string absent_type, 
                                       string description, 
                                       int point_value)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get id for the absent type
            int absent_type_id = db.AT_absent_types.Single(a => a.absent_type == absent_type).absent_type_id;

            var occurrenceToUpdate = new AT_occurrences
            {
                occ_id = occ_id,
                absent_type_id = absent_type_id,
                description = description,
                point_value = point_value
            };

            db.AT_occurrences.Attach(occurrenceToUpdate);

            db.SaveChanges();

            //return call omitted
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new {Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message});
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned - posting the point_value and absent_type save and update the entity perfectly, the description just will not save! i have no idea why.  Any help or insight would be very much appreciated - this is driving me crazy!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You use "Attach" to attach a disconnected property to the context. My understanding is Entity Framework has no way of knowing that the properties you're changing are different from those in the DB. So you have to explicitly tell the EF that you've changed a property. 
Like this:

```
db.Entry(occurenceToUpdate).Property(o=>o.occ_id).IsModified = true;
```

or like this:

```
db.Entry(occurenceToUpdate).Property("occ_id").IsModified = true;
```

You'll have to repeat it for each properties you're setting.

I know for sure the above works but you can also try the following. If you're setting all the properties of the entity object, check if something like this works:

```
db.Entry(occurenceToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified.
```

Comment: Thanks for the resoinse SashaArz.  I added the lines as you suggested.  It however did nothing it seems.  If I post to the method a new type, description, and point value - the type and point value both get updated in the table, but the description does not.  how can that be!

Comment: Was description field added to the table at a later time or renamed?

Comment: It is possible it was added to the table after it was created.  Could that cause an issue?  The table has the description column as "varchar(800)" and the entity has "public string description { get; set; }"...so EF knows it's there.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but whenever I face a similar issue with EF, I delete the table completely, then build.  If you're using TFS, you can always undo your pending changes if this doesn't work, which is the caveat I use when I do this for myself.

Comment: Thanks Lexi - I am not sure I want to go ahead and do that yet...though I am really not sure what else to do...I cannot see why this column just wont save - no errors or anything, just wont take.